# Change interface orientation from subview - iOS

Tags: ios, subview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an iPhone app that is always portrait. But I need to rotate a view to show a table.
The button is located in a subview. I have this code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

But because this view is called from a subview, interface orientation is ignored.

Are there any way to change the interface orientation??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the transform on the view you want to rotate, and set it back to the identity transform afterwards.

This will toggle between portrait and landscape...

```
 UIView* viewToTransform = self.newview;
    if (CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(viewToTransform.transform)) {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
        viewToTransform.transform = transform;

    }else{
        viewToTransform.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
```

Better still, save the existing transform in a property so that you can reset it later (this would deal with cases where the original transform is not the identity transform).

Comment: i did that but it doesn't results, maybe i need some imports?? thanks!

Comment: are you trying to rotate everything onscreen or just one subview?